# How to sum value at every step of CSV Column

Tags: python, iteration

so I am using this code to get the frequency of searched words in Google Trends:

```
import pandas as pd
from pytrends.request import TrendReq
pytrend = TrendReq(hl='en-US', tz=360)
keywords = ['Python', 'R']
pytrend.build_payload(
     kw_list=keywords,
     cat=0,
     timeframe='today 3-m',
     geo='TW',
     gprop='')
data = pytrend.interest_over_time()
data= data.drop(labels=['isPartial'],axis='columns')
image = data.plot(title = 'Python V.S. R in last 3 months on Google Trends ')
fig = image.get_figure()
fig.savefig('figure.png')
data.to_csv('Py_VS_R.csv', encoding='utf_8_sig')
```

which results in a table like this, showing the frequency of each day:

```
            Python       R  
date
2017-10-23      3       1      
2017-10-24      1       2
2017-10-25      5       1      
2017-10-26      3       4      
2017-10-27      1       5      
2017-10-28      2       1
```

but I want every value of the column to sum with each other, like this:

```
       Python       R  
date
2017-10-23      3       1      
2017-10-24      4       3
2017-10-25      9       4      
2017-10-26      12      8      
2017-10-27      13      13      
2017-10-28      15      14
```

so that the last row value of the column would be the total number.
What is the best way to do it? Can I achieve this through Pytrends?
Or do I need to write a seperate code?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the rest of the code is correct, you could achieve the cumulative sum simply by using pandas's cumsum() method as **data.cumsum()**

```
import pandas as pd
from pytrends.request import TrendReq
pytrend = TrendReq(hl='en-US', tz=360)
keywords = ['Python', 'R']
pytrend.build_payload(
     kw_list=keywords,
     cat=0,
     timeframe='today 3-m',
     geo='TW',
     gprop='')
data = pytrend.interest_over_time()
data= data.drop(labels=['isPartial'],axis='columns')
data = data.cumsum()
image = data.plot(title = 'Python V.S. R in last 3 months on Google Trends ')
fig = image.get_figure()
fig.savefig('figure.png')
data.to_csv('Py_VS_R.csv', encoding='utf_8_sig')
```

Comment: you're the man, thanks a lot! :) worked as intended